# Asp.net core 1.0 and Angular 1 routing issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp.net core 1.0 application (MVC) + AngularJS 1. I have an controller `Home` with action `Index` looking like that

```
[Route("UsersModule/[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : UsersModuleControllerBase, IWebFrameModuleController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The `UsersModule/Home/Index` view looks like that:

```
... 

<div id="usersModule">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

...
```

I dynamically bootstrap angular on that div element.

Imagine 2 angular routes. The first one is the default (`$routeProvider.otherwise` route) one.

```
//1
"templateUrl": "Modules/UsersModule/app/users/pages/users.html",
"controller": "usersModule.UsersCtrl"

 //2 
"url": "/users",
"templateUrl": "Modules/UsersModule/app/users/pages/users.html",
"controller": "usersModule.UsersCtrl"
```

So when I browse `http://localhost/<app_name>/UsersModule/Home/Index` I get everything right - the angular template and controller are loaded, etc.

**The problem**

But when I browse `http://localhost/<app_name>/UsersModule/Home/Index#/users`. The browse rewrites the url to `http://localhost/<app_name>/UsersModule/Home/Index#!#%2Fusers` and nothing happens, no js errors, no request has been made, etc.

This escaping of the characters is something new and I am thinking that probably this is the cause of my not-loading issue. I didn't have any issues before the asp.net core.

I will copy-paste part of my `Startup.cs` file as well:

in `ConfigureServices` I have that

```
var mvcBuilder = services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.None;
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                })
                .AddMvcOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionHandlerFilter(log4netLogger));
                });
```

`Configure` method:

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();

 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Main" });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mention that I was using 1.5.5 angularjs. I upgraded the angular to the latest 1.5.8.

In addition to this, I deleted all packages from 
`<user_folder>\.nuget\packages` and `<user_folder>\.nuget\.tools` and I did a restore packages on my solution.

After all of that everything now is back to normal and it's working. No strange URL encoding, etc.

I also tried to downgrade the AngularJS version to the 1.5.5 and I started getting the strange encoding urls and it was working partly (not everything was fine though).

Hope this can be helpful to someone having the same problem.